# Displaying uploaded image from database to my ASP.NET MVC view

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm on the newer side of working with C# and I am contributing to a multi-page website, I am creating a blog section of the site that has a create view that allows for a title field and file upload, which is converted to a byte array and then stored in the database, and then I want to pull the image from the database using the attached ID and display the image onto the edit, index, and details views.

I was able to do the first step few steps just fine. The file upload now converts to a `byte[]` and is stored in the database as such. I now need help because I am having trouble displaying this in my view.

I have tried this in my `Index` view to display the image.

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,@(Convert.ToBase64String(Model.BlogPhotoes.Photo))">
```

This does not work. There is an error at `Model.BlogPhotoes.Photo`:

> IEnumerable does not contain a definition for 'BlogPhotoes' and no accessible extension method 'BlogPhotoes' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have also tried just doing `Model.Photo` instead, but the same error is thrown.

I have also tried converting directly to an image in the controller, which didn't work.

```
public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] src)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(src);
    Image bytePhoto = Image.FromStream(ms);
    return bytePhoto;
}
```

Here's my full code if it needs to be seen.

Model class:

```
public class BlogPhoto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class BlogPhotoesController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    // GET: Blog/BlogPhotoes
    public ActionResult Index()
    { 
        return View(db.BlogPhotoes.ToList());
    }

    // GET: Blog/BlogPhotoes/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        BlogPhoto blogPhoto = db.BlogPhotoes.Find(id);

        if (blogPhoto == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View(blogPhoto);
    }

    // GET: Blog/BlogPhotoes/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Blog/BlogPhotoes/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Title,Photo")] BlogPhoto blogPhoto, HttpPostedFileBase userPhoto) 
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) 
        {
            byte[] bytePhoto = ConvertToByte(userPhoto); 
            blogPhoto.Photo = bytePhoto;

            db.BlogPhotoes.Add(blogPhoto); 
            db.SaveChanges(); 

            return RedirectToAction("Index", bytePhoto); 
        }

        return View(blogPhoto);
    }

    // GET: Blog/BlogPhotoes/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        BlogPhoto blogPhoto = db.BlogPhotoes.Find(id);

        if (blogPhoto == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View(blogPhoto);
    }

    // POST: Blog/BlogPhotoes/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Title,Photo")] BlogPhoto blogPhoto)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(blogPhoto).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(blogPhoto);
    }

    // GET: Blog/BlogPhotoes/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        BlogPhoto blogPhoto = db.BlogPhotoes.Find(id);

        if (blogPhoto == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View(blogPhoto);
    }

    // POST: Blog/BlogPhotoes/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        BlogPhoto blogPhoto = db.BlogPhotoes.Find(id);
        db.BlogPhotoes.Remove(blogPhoto);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    public byte[] ConvertToByte(HttpPostedFileBase photo)
    {
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
        //MemoryStream allows us to store bytes coming from another place
        //i instantiate it so that I can store the photo into it's instance,
        //then I can set it equal the bytePhoto byte array.
        photo.InputStream.CopyTo(memStream);
        byte[] bytePhoto = memStream.ToArray();
        return bytePhoto;
    }
}
```

`Index` view:

```
@model IEnumerable<TheatreCMS4.Areas.Models.BlogPhoto>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Photo)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,@(Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Photo))">

        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Any help is appreciated. I've been stuck on this for going on 11 hours.

Thank you so much for your time.